# Wordpress.com post editor replacement

Tags: posts, wordpress.com-hosting, editor

I love Wordpress, and I keep a blog on a domain hosted at wordpress.com. However, it's so damn slow! (Blogger wasn't much better.) Are there any full-featured substitutes available?

I use several computers, depending on where I am and what I'm doing: An older mac, a windows netbook, and a ChromeOS laptop, so the best solutions for me will be web-based, but I won't rule out desktop apps.

Aside from the slowness, I can't stand the little tiny window in the posyst editor (there's a fullscreen view, but not in code view), and as I tend to edit the HTML directly, syntax highlighting would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress.com supports post editing via the XML-RPC protocol. There are [many editors that support this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Weblog_Client) so you can write your posts on your own computer and post them to WordPress.com (or your own hosted WordPress installation). The better clients are smart enough to sync content, so if you use different editors on different computers they will check for new content (probably also drafts) and allow you to edit that too.

If you find another web-based blogging platform that has a nicer editor, it might be possible to create a "hidden" blog there and send your posts to your WordPress.com blog. I have a client that does this with Posterous because he prefers the post-by-mail functionality there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution for the syntax highlighting, but regarding the HTML window size, you can make make the editor window larger by dragging the bottom right corner.

In Chrome and Safari, you can do this from the HTML screen.  In Firefox and IE, you have to go to the VISUAL editor screen, drag to enlarge there, then switch back to the HTML view.

Hope this helps until you find the perfect solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, the window goes back to normal size every time I save. (Chrome, in Google ChromeOS.)

Comment: On the Mac, Safari behaves the same way. On Firefox on the Mac, the resize UI widget doesn't even appear. :(

Comment: @neilfein - I don't those changes are permanent, on Firefox be sure to check the visual editor for the resize, on FF for windows it only appears on the visual---sorry